# How to get product title in cart in new woocommerce 3.x

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have this problem in a plugin, I managed to solve all errors except this one.
Here is the original code...

```
$products = WC()->cart->cart_contents;
$cartTitles = '';
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $cartTitles .= $product['quantity'] . '-' . $product['data']->post->post_title;
}
```

I'm getting here the typical notice message -

```
Post was called incorrectly.  Properties should not be accessed directly.
```

How can I get the post title?  I tried with `$product['data']->get_post()` but it triggers an error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
 $product['data']->get_title();
```

Comment: Exactly. The `$product['data']` variable is a `WC_Product` class product object. You need to use getters ex: `$product->get_id()` to get all class properties you used to access directly ex: `$product->id`